# Определить, есть ли слово в массиве php

Tags: php, массивы

Дана случайная строка, пример

```
$str = "Один два три четыре пять";
```

Есть заданный массив

```
$array[0] = array('яблоко', 'четыре', 'кактус');
```

Задача, проверить, есть ли в строке $str слово, которое совпадает с элементом массива $array[0].
Желательно без циклов, если возможно. Если невозможно, то как можно оптимизированее для большого трафика.

Сейчас код такой

```
if (in_array(mb_strtolower($str), $array[0])) {
    //true
}
```

Но такой код сверяет всю строку с массивом. 
Первое что приходит в голову: разбить строку через explode(), и потом проверять каждое слово циклом через in_array. Но боюсь это все повиснет при большом потоке, может есть какая либо функция, для моей задачи?

Comment: Без цикла не получится. Вам надо перебирать элементы массива (вот он цикл) и поэлементно сравнивать со строкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть вариант использовать функцию [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), если результат функции будет пустой значит совпадений нет, если нет - значит совпадения есть, но перед этим строку через explode по пробелу превратим в массив:

```
$array[0] = array('яблоко', 'четыре', 'кактус');

$str = "Один два три четыре пять";

if (array_intersect(explode(' ', $str), $array[0])) {
    echo 'Совпадение есть';
}
else {
    echo 'Совпадений нет';
}
```

Выведет что совпадения есть.

Comment: то что нужно и без циклов, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = mb_strtolower($str);

foreach ($array[0] as $word) {
    if (strpos($str, $word) >= 0) {
        //слово есть
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `var_dump(false >= 0); // true, поэтому ваш ответ не сработает`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $str = "Один два три четыре пять";
 $array[0] = array('яблоко', 'четыре', 'кактус');
 $boo = "Ни один элемент массива не обнаружен в строке";
 foreach($array[0] as $search){
 $pos = strpos($str, $search);
 if ($pos !== false) {
    $boo = "Элемент '$search' найден в строке '$str'";
    break;
  }
}
 echo $boo;
?>
```